# Couldn't share note with evernote api in cordova app

Tags: cordova, evernote

Based on the minified version of evernote-sdk-js, In a phonegap application, i'm able to retrieve the list of notes by using a noteStore.
Function to get NoteStore :

```
createNoteStore : function(options) {
                    var noteStoreURL = options.edam_noteStoreUrl;
                    var noteStoreTransport = new Thrift.BinaryHttpTransport(
                            noteStoreURL);
                    var noteStoreProtocol = new Thrift.BinaryProtocol(
                            noteStoreTransport);
                    return new NoteStoreClient(noteStoreProtocol);
                };
```

With this function i'm able to get the list of notes

```
function getList(){
                                    var $callback = $.Deferred();
                    createNoteStore(params).listNotebooks(
                            params.oauth_token, function
   onSuccess(notebooks) {
                                $callback.resolve(notebooks);
                            }, function onerror(error) {
                                $callback.reject(notebooks);
                            });
                    return $callback;
}
```

Now I'm looking to share a single note or to search for notes with some key words by using 'findNotesMetadata' and findNotes, none of them works with **EDAMUserException {errorCode: 3, parameter: "authenticationToken"}**

```
function Search(word, options, params){
                                    var $callback = $.Deferred();
                    if (!params) {
                        throw new Error('missing required parametres');
                    }
                    var filter = new NoteFilter();
                    filter.words = 'notebook:' + word + ' ';
                    var spec = new NotesMetadataResultSpec();
                    spec.includeTitle = true;
                    // if !options.noteStore && !
                    // create
                    api.createNoteStore(params).findNotes(
                    params.oauth_token, filter, 0, 100, spec,
                            function onSuccess(notebooks) {
                                $callback.resolve(notebooks);
                            }, function onerror(error) {
                                $callback.reject(error);
                            });
                    return $callback;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

errorCode:3 is [PERMISSION_DENIED](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Errors.html#Enum_EDAMErrorCode) so it's probably because you don't have permission on your API key. With basic access, you can list notebooks but if you want to access your notes, you need full access. See [this page](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/permissions.php) about permissions.

You can check your API key's permission during the OAuth process. If this is the case, re-create the API key with full permission would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @kentaro, that's right, i created a new application with full access permission.
Still can't search for notebooks from documentation  (fine with notes) but this is another question. thanks !